# What does 0x4 do in "movl $0x2d, 0x4(%esp)"?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

I am looking into assembly code generated by GCC. But I don't understand:

```
movl $0x2d, 0x4(%esp)
```

In the second operand, what does `0x4` stands for? offset address?  And what the use of register EAX?

Comment: It means memory[ESP_REG + 4] = 0x2d;

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`movl $0x2d, 0x4(%esp)` means to take the current value of the stack pointer (`%esp`), add 4 (`0x4`) then store the long (32-bit) value `0x2d` into that location.

The `eax` register is one of the general purpose 32-bit registers. x86 architecture specifies the following 32-bit registers:

```
eax  Accumulator Register
ebx  Base Register
ecx  Counter Register
edx  Data Register
esi  Source Index
edi  Destination Index
ebp  Base Pointer
esp  Stack Pointer
```

and the names and purposes of some of then harken back to the days of the Intel 8080.

[This page](http://www.swansontec.com/sregisters.html) gives a good overview on the Intel-type registers. The first four of those in the above list can also be accessed as a 16-bit or two 8-bit values as well. For example:

```
3322222222221111111111
10987654321098765432109876543210
<-             eax            ->
                <-     ax     ->
                <- ah -><- al ->
```

The pointer and index registers do not allow use of 8-bit parts but you can have, for example, the 16-bit `bp`.

Comment: +1 - It's 'AT&T' notation not Intel notation which is what gcc outputs i.e the source and dest are swapped around from the Intel notation

Comment: And Intel notation doesn't require field length on the operator i.e. mov, not movl. But, very informative answer - +1.

Answer (score 4):

`0x4(%esp)` means `*(%esp + 4)` where `*` mean dereferencing.

The statement means store the immediate value 0x2d into some local variable occupying the 4th offset on the stack.

(The code you've shown is in AT&T syntax. In Intel syntax it would be `mov [esp, 4], 2dh`)

Answer (score 1):

`0x4` in the second operand is an offset from the value of the register in the parens. `EAX` is a general purpose register used for assembly coding (computations, storing temporary values, etc.) formally it's called "Accumulator register" but that's more historic than relevant.

You can read [this page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/X86_Architecture) about the x86 architecture. Most relevant to your question are the sections on *Addressing modes* and *General purpose registers*

Answer (score 1):

GCC assembly operands follow a byte (b), word (w), long (l) and so on such as :

```
movb
movw
movl
```

Registers are prefixed with a percentage sign (%).

Constants are prefixed with a dollar sign ($).

In the above example in your question that means the 4th offset from the stack pointer (esp).

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing something four bytes removed from where the stack pointer resides.  In GCC this indicates a parameter (I think -- positive offset is parameters and negative is local variables if I remember correctly).  You're writing, in other words, the value 0x2D into a parameter.  If you gave more context I could probably tell you what was going on in the whole procedure.